# Auto-Deploy Docker-Python application with Heroku

Tags: python, docker, heroku, swagger, web-deployment

I have a Docker-application, that i build and run with:

```sh
docker build -t swagger_server .
docker run -p 8080:8080 swagger_server
```

The `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM python:3-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["-m", "swagger_server"]
```

This in and of itself is fairly simple, but I'm struggling with deploying this Dockerfile to Heroku. I have connected Heroku to auto-deploy on every push, but haven't configured anything up until now. It builds and runs the application successfully, but i think it only runs the python-application without exposing any ports.

Heroku have [a documentation-page on their website](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml), however I don't understand how to specify ports or build-tags in `heroku.yml`.

To give some more context: I want to deploy a Python/Flask-Application that was auto-generated by the swagger-codegen. I can access the API locally, no matter if I run it within a conda-environment or with docker.

Can somebody explain to me how that should work?

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy with Docker with Heroku, EXPOSE port manually in Docker won't be respected, the port to be exposed will be determined automatically by Heroku.

Your app must listening in `$PORT` (env set by Heroku).

Another thing to note is, when you start swagger server, you must allow traffic coming from all IPs, otherwise it'll only be reachable in `localhost` (notice that this localhost is the container itself).

```py
import os

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=os.getenv('PORT'))
```